# Calling teardown when nosetests fail

Tags: nose

I'm creating a temporary db in setup that I'm then deleting in teardown. But if my tests fail, it never gets around to teardown, what is the best practice to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From nose [docs](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#fixtures)

> teardown runs if setup has completed successfully, regardless of the
>   status of the test run.

So as long as your setup for temporary db succeeds, you should be fine.